# useMediaQuery performance - Should I pass it in props or just call it again in the nested component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

For best practices/performance, should I `useMediaQuery` once and pass it in the `props`? or should I just call `useMediaQuery` again in the nested component? Or it doesn't really matter?

So, just for example is this better:

```js
function ParentComponent() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints('sm'));

    // Used isMobile for something (whatever it is)    

    return <div>
        <ChildComponent isMobile={isMobile}/>
    </div>
}

function ChildComponent({isMobile}) {
    // Used isMobile for something (whatever it is)   

    return <div>This is a child</div> 
}
```

Or should I do this?

```js
function ParentComponent() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints('sm'));

    // Used isMobile for something (whatever it is)    

    return <div>
        <ChildComponent/>
    </div>
}

function ChildComponent() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints('sm'));

    // Used isMobile for something (whatever it is)   

    return <div>This is a child</div> 
}
```

Or both will perform exactly the same?

I know both will work, What I want to know is one is a better practice or which one is better in terms of performance

Comment: I would expect the first to perform slightly better, but I wouldn’t expect the difference to be enough to worry about in most cases. If you have a large array of children, then it might add up to something worth tuning.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge.If our multiple components going to use same code then configure that code in separate file like Config.js(or Utils.js) and then we can place our code and export from that folder so we can use this code in multiple places.Now in future if any changes arrives in this code we just need to change only one place in our Config.js file and change is apply to every places.

```
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";

const theme = useTheme();
const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints("sm"));

export { isMobile };
```

Comment: let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I'm asking, I know what you're talking about and yes it is best practice to take it out in a separate file, but I'll try to elaborate, even if I use your example, should I `import {isMobile}` in both `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`? or should I just import it in `ParentComponent` and pass it down in the `props` to `ChildComponent`?

Comment: as per me you just need to import {isMobile} in both ParentComponent and ChildComponent is best idea because if you are importing it to your parent and then you need to pass it as child  then you have it access it as props in this case you have to remember that you are passing it from parent and  using it in child. which you will going to forgot in future and then you have to check it step by step again

Answer (score 0):

I fully understood your question. I don't see any difference about performance and also I have been searching about useMediaQuery and have not found anything about our question. And I think you can just use how it is comfortable for you, for me its comfortoble and more readable to use it anywhere you need, don't think about it so much. And later if you will find new information about it, or realize yourself that it influence to performance, you can just change the way, and just store in your store(redux for example). But right now I use this hook how you do in 2nd variant. [image: 2nd variant]